# Abstract Factory "java.lang.IllegalAccessError" issue

Tags: java, adapter

I am learning about Design patterns currently with the rest of my class. We have been tasked with creating an adapter.

I can't make the code generate and I'm not sure why, I've shown the code to other classmates and they say it is more or less the same as theirs, yet there's works.

Test file to run against

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] theArguments) {
    Truck t=new vehicleAdapter();
    t.setWheel(6);
    System.out.println("Number of wheels: " + t.getWheel() + "!");
  }
}
```

Car logger

```
  private int wheels;

  public double getwheel(){
    return wheels;
  }
  public void setWheel(int numberOfWheels){
    wheels = numberOfWheels;
  }
}
```

Truck Logger

```
interface Truck {
  public void setWheel(int numberOfWheels);
  public int getWheel();
}
```

Adapter

```
import java.lang.*;

class vehicleAdapter implements Truck {
  Car c = new Car();

  public void setWheel(int truckWheels) {
    c.setWheel(truckWheels);

  }
  public int getWheel(){
    return c.getWheel()
  }
}
```

Note: This is similar version to what has been asked in class, it is not, the outputs are irrelevant, everything compiles. However, when I run Test.java I get:

note: vehicleAdapter is symbolic

```
failed to access class vehicleAdapter from class Test (vehicleAdapter is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; Test is in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main$MemoryClassLoader @1ad282e0)
```

Any help would be welcome and I am happy to improve this post.

Comment: Based on that error message you're (accidentally?) using [this feature](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330) that was added in Java 11. You should be using `java Test` (after compiling the code), not `java Test.java`.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you, this was it! I forgot that I had uninstalled the most recent Java for 8 to do a particular tutorial, thank you so much :)